# Load users from backend using angular / express

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, angular5

Im doing a little project with the MEAN stack and seem to be a little lost with something here. I can load a single user from MongoDB just fine, but I seem to be a little lost with loading all.

In my routes file I have

```
router.get('/admin, function(req, res, next) {
  User.find(function (err, user) {
    if(err) return next(err);
  }
});
```

I get the results from the database such as:

```
{"role":"user","_id":"5ade3f1c303744098c0acef1","firstname":"testFName","surname":"testSName","username":"testusername","password":"$2a$10$db1yx10Y3XOyyMt25PA5bOK3qso9fTxf9iOOWMapT7/Vt5n2gfCFC","email":"testemail@email.com","phonenumber":"0851234567","housename":"Villa Maria","addressline1":"Listry","addressline2":"Killarney","addressline3":"","county":"Kerry","__v":0}
```

Im following a guide, but it doesn't seem to cover this next part, I was wondering if anyone knew what I should do. I do know that I want to use *ngFor in a table somewhere.

I have called my authService and my router in my constructor

```
user: Object;

ngOnInit(){
  this.loadUsers();
}

public loadUsers() {
  this.authService.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
    this.user = data;
}
```

in my table I was using

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of users">
  <td>{{ user.username }} </td>
```

But I keep getting a not defined error. I can't seem to see how it is not defined.

Comment: `'user' != 'users'`. Also you should think about what happens before the subscription resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty standard mistake. Angular gives you this error because it tries to render `*ngFor` **immediately** upon component creation while calling service takes time and it brings result later. You should add something like `*ngIf="users != null"` to your template and put `*ngFor` inside it. Always check the array you're going to render with `*ngFor` to avoid this error, or make sure in the code that your array property never gets `null` or `undefined` value.

Comment: thank you =]  
added it to the <tbody> and it fixed the issue